# Python Selenium selectors - Dropdown icon?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selector

I have this drop icon element. How do I need to use it with the Xpath? or which I need to use?

[image]

is a burger dropdown menu. I don't know how to use it with the XPath

[image]

Comment: Images of text are not searchable, nor are they accessible. Please augment them with the text they contain or replace them with the text they contain.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//i[@class='q-icon material-icons']").click()
```